# Updating RTK (redux toolkit) state using other state values

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-toolkit

Can I update the state based on other state variables (as shown below in `setCurrentQuestion()`), or will it cause unexpected issues?

I can think of two workarounds:

1. "external" helper function that calls a `getCurrentQuestionIndex()` selector passed into a `getQuestionByIndex()` selector which returns an `IQuestion` object that I pass into the `setCurrentQuestion()` reducer
2. Keep as is but use a [draft safe selector](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createSelector) instead of accessing the state object directly

```js
const slice = createSlice({
    name: 'blabla',
    initialState: { questions: undefined, currentQuestion: undefined, noOfQuestions: 0, currentQuestionIndex: 0 } as QuizState,
    reducers: {
        setQuestions: (state, action: PayloadAction<IQuestion[]>) => {
            state.questions = action.payload;
        },
        setCurrentQuestion: (state, action: PayloadAction<number>) => {
            if (!state.questions) return
            state.currentQuestion = state.questions[state.currentQuestionIndex]
        }
    },
```

Answer (score 1):

`state.currentQuestion` should simply not exist in your state. You got `state.questions` as the source of truth, and `state.currentQuestionIndex` to remember which question is the current question. Anything further is not atomic and minimal anymore. It certainly works to have a `state.currentQuestion` which duplicates one of the items in `state.questions`, but then you end up with problems like this one. I'd recommend to add a selector `getCurrentQuestion()` that does the lookup and that can deal with `state.questions` being falsy. It also should never not be an array btw, it's easier to deal with state if the types don't change. I'd initialise it as an empty array, and then the selector could be:

```
const getCurrentQuestion = (state) => state.questions[state.currentQuestionIndex];
```

To solve what you had in mind, looking at a different part of the state before mutating it in the reducer, you could also use a thunk - they have `getState()` in the scope and can run conditional logic. So you could simply not dispatch `setCurrentQuestion` if `state.questions` is falsy. But a better solution imo is what I described above with the selector.

Comment: You are totally right regarding storing the question as a separate state instead of simply accessing it. Bad design (I'll blame the time ;)). Not sure if thunks are the best solution here. Based on the documentation the `draftSafeSelector` looks like the more appropriate approach

Comment: There's always multiple ways to solve a problem I guess. After reading the doc for `createDraftSafeSelector` (which describe them as "selectors that will work correctly inside of Immer-powered reducers") I can't quite make out the connection to your use case - updating state based on other state. `createDraftSafeSelector` seems to be much more specialized and niche than the fundamental challenge you described.